# Validate drop down list via Coldfusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion-8

This seems simple enough, but I'm not able to figure out why this code will not validate:  http://pastebin.com/R6nQ8ZER

I previously got help to make textboxes appear depending on which option was selected from a drop down list.  It seems as though the logic for the drop down list may not allow me to validate the selected option.

Each time an option is selected and the form is submitted, the error appears to select an affiliation and the drop down list clears my selection.  I thought it was the cfparam erasing my selection, but another stripping down attempt proved it was not the cfparam

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I didn't name the select list so the code didn't know what to look for.  I simply overlooked this attribute but have since corrected it.